# How to get all possible combination from n list in MsSql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For ex.

I have three list like as below

```
List1
--------
A,
B

List2
--------
C,
D

List3
--------
E,
F
```

I want to write query to get all 8 possible combination from above three list
    Accepted Output

```
(1) A C E,
(2) A C F,
(3) A D E,
(4) A D F,
(5) B C E,
(6) B C F,
(7) B D E,
(8) B D F,
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple cross join:

```
SELECT l1.*, l2.*, l3.*
FROM List1 l1, List2 l2, List3 l3;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f498ee2ec1d823686211fc7e7ec5e6dd)**

Comment: It's better to use `CROSS JOIN` than this comma separated `FROM` list...

Comment: @Shnugo I agree that `CROSS JOIN` is more explicit, but `,` is shorter. I think that using `,` when there is no other "JOINS INNER/OUTER` then it is acceptable

Comment: Yeah, you are rigth of course. Your statement *when there is no other "JOINS INNER/OUTER"* is the crucial point. But in this simple case there's no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all possible combinations by using following code:

```
Select *
from List1 CROSS JOIN
List2 CROSS JOIN
List3;
```

Comment: Glad to help you!